# cakephp puts the checkbox on separate lines

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am generating checkboxes like this

```
foreach($apps as $app){
        echo $this->Form->input($app['Application']['description'], array('type'=>'checkbox','value' => $app['Application']['description']));

    }
```

and it put check boxes like

```
checkbox 1
checkbox 2
checkbox 3
```

where as I want

```
checkbox1 checkbox2 checkbox3
```

**tried**

```
$x = '';
    foreach($apps as $app){
            $x .= $this->Form->input($app['Application']['description'], array('div'=>false,'type'=>'checkbox','value' => $app['Application']['description']));

        }

echo $x;
```

Comment: tried div = false but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake does not put it on a separate line, the CSS for your input div or label do. Look at your CSS for the input div and label (check the class name by viewing the source) to make sure you have `display:inline` set.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this question:

In your css file (in my case "cake.generic.css") put this:

```
.checkbox{
   padding-right: 15px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

And in your .ctp file:

```
$this->Form->input('fieldName',[
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
  ]);
```